# How to add an option to admin to add image that could be used as header?

Tags: custom-field, customization, themes

I want to add an option to add/change an Image in admin dashboard in a way that I can call it through code. For example lets call it header_2 Image and then want to use it in an header template. So that users later on can change this image without editing header template.

Comment: You do not save an image in the database. You save them on your server(or cloud). Also your requirement seems too generic. Please be a bit more specific.

Comment: I want to add an option to add/change  an Image in admin dashboard in a way that I can call it through code. For example lets call it header_2 Image and then want to use it in an header template. So that users later on can change this image without editing header template. I can add this to question if it makes sense.

Comment: For me that still needs improvement. From my experience i can tell that you get the best response if you are more clear. We also would like to see what you did so far.

Comment: sri. I guess it is difficult requirement to explain. SO I have left answer which meets the requirements but, please answer if you have a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it in the end. 
I installed [Types](http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) plugin and created a custom post type with only featured Image and title.

I created one post of this type.

Removed GUI to add more posts of this type.

Using another plugin [Admin Menu Editor](http://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/) I added menu Item to edit the only post of this custom type. Now this Image can be changed at any time.

and I displayed featured Image of this post in the page I had to. Once this post is changed. It changes in the page as well.

More like a tweak but for user it is very easy to use and works as required.